# iteration that creates dataframe from 1:nth value, then deletes the first value and adds the next value in line

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I have a question regarding the creation of multiple dataframes. Below is the initial dataframe.

```
framework <- structure(list(game_id = c(303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 
303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 
303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 303731L, 
303731L, 303731L), home_team = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), team_name = c("Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
"Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
"Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
"Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
"Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona"), player_name = c("Antoine Griezmann", 
"Sergio Busquets i Burgos", "Sergio Busquets i Burgos", "Sergio Busquets i Burgos", 
"Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo", "Héctor Junior Firpo Adames", "Héctor Junior Firpo Adames", 
"Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo", "Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo", "Jordi Alba Ramos", 
"Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo", "Gerard Piqué Bernabéu", 
"Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo", "Samuel Yves Umtiti", 
"Clément Lenglet", "Clément Lenglet", "Gerard Piqué Bernabéu", 
"Gerard Piqué Bernabéu", "Clément Lenglet", "Clément Lenglet"
), type_name = c("pass", "dribble", "dribble", "pass", "dribble", 
"dribble", "pass", "dribble", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", "dribble", 
"pass", "dribble", "dribble", "pass", "dribble", "pass", "dribble", 
"pass"), result_name = c("success", "success", "success", "success", 
"success", "success", "success", "success", "success", "success", 
"success", "success", "success", "success", "success", "success", 
"success", "success", "success", "success"), no_passes = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8), subs = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 77131:77150, class = "data.frame")
```

## Output

```
      game_id home_team team_name                            player_name type_name result_name no_passes subs
77131  303731      TRUE Barcelona                      Antoine Griezmann      pass     success         1    0
77132  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos   dribble     success         1    0
77133  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos   dribble     success         1    0
77134  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      pass     success         2    0
77135  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         2    0
77136  303731      TRUE Barcelona             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames   dribble     success         2    0
77137  303731      TRUE Barcelona             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames      pass     success         3    0
77138  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         3    0
77139  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo      pass     success         4    0
77140  303731      TRUE Barcelona                       Jordi Alba Ramos   dribble     success         4    0
77141  303731      TRUE Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo   dribble     success         4    0
77142  303731      TRUE Barcelona                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu   dribble     success         4    0
77143  303731      TRUE Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo      SUB      success         5    1
77144  303731      TRUE Barcelona                     Samuel Yves Umtiti   dribble     success         5    0
77145  303731      TRUE Barcelona                        Clément Lenglet   dribble     success         5    0
77146  303731      TRUE Barcelona                        Clément Lenglet      pass     success         6    0
77147  303731      TRUE Barcelona                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu   dribble     success         6    0
77148  303731      TRUE Barcelona                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu      pass     success         7    0
77149  303731      TRUE Barcelona                        Clément Lenglet   dribble     success         7    0
77150  303731      TRUE Barcelona                        Clément Lenglet      pass     success         8    0
```

What I would like to do now, is do an iteration with the column `no_passes`, creating multiple dataframes. The idea is that the first dataframe consist of `no_passes == 1`, towards `no_passes == 4`.

Each new dataframe should delete the first `no_passes` and add the next `no_passes` in line (thus the 11th in this case).

The second dataframe should thus include everything between `no_passes == 2` and `no_passes == 5`

This should iterate until the last `no_passes`, which is 8.

Below is the expected output of the first two dataframes

## output 1

```
      game_id home_team team_name                            player_name type_name result_name no_passes subs
77131  303731      TRUE Barcelona                      Antoine Griezmann      pass     success         1    0  
77132  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos   dribble     success         1    0  
77133  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos   dribble     success         1    0  
77134  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      pass     success         2    0  
77135  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         2    0  
77136  303731      TRUE Barcelona             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames   dribble     success         2    0  
77137  303731      TRUE Barcelona             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames      pass     success         3    0  
77138  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         3    0  
77139  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo      pass     success         4    0  
77140  303731      TRUE Barcelona                       Jordi Alba Ramos   dribble     success         4    0  
77141  303731      TRUE Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo   dribble     success         4    0  
77142  303731      TRUE Barcelona                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu   dribble     success         4    0
```

## output 2

```
      game_id home_team team_name                            player_name type_name result_name no_passes subs  
77134  303731      TRUE Barcelona               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      pass     success         2    0  
77135  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         2    0  
77136  303731      TRUE Barcelona             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames   dribble     success         2    0  
77137  303731      TRUE Barcelona             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames      pass     success         3    0  1
77138  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         3    0  
77139  303731      TRUE Barcelona              Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo      pass     success         4    0  
77140  303731      TRUE Barcelona                       Jordi Alba Ramos   dribble     success         4    0  
77141  303731      TRUE Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo   dribble     success         4    0  
77142  303731      TRUE Barcelona                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu   dribble     success         4    0  
77143  303731      TRUE Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo      SUB      success         5    1  1
77144  303731      TRUE Barcelona                     Samuel Yves Umtiti   dribble     success         5    0  
77145  303731      TRUE Barcelona                        Clément Lenglet   dribble     success         5    0
```

My current code looks like the following and gives the following output:

```
# First, create an empty datalist.
datalist_HT <- list()

# Create the 4-pass frame (with all actions between as well) for Home team
  for(j in seq_len(nrow(framework))-4){
    
    # 1: Grab first 4 no_passes starting from j
    passes_j <- framework[j:(j+4), ]
    
# now store each dataframe in a list
datalist_HT[[j]] <- passes_j

}

# Output
      game_id home_team team_name               player_name type_name result_name no_passes subs 
77131  303731      TRUE Barcelona         Antoine Griezmann      pass     success         1    0
77132  303731      TRUE Barcelona  Sergio Busquets i Burgos   dribble     success         1    0
77133  303731      TRUE Barcelona  Sergio Busquets i Burgos   dribble     success         1    0
77134  303731      TRUE Barcelona  Sergio Busquets i Burgos      pass     success         2    0
77135  303731      TRUE Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo   dribble     success         2    0
```

However, I tend to only get the first 4 entries instead of everything within the first 4 `no_passes`.

## Summary

- Create multiple dataframes, each consisting of 4 sequential `no_passes` (see output 1 and output 2

I hope I made myself clear enough, I don't really know how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Focus on one issue, and please also show your attempts.

Comment: Check answer below.  If you want to convert each of list item into a separate DF, then leave a comment. It however depends upon your ultimate objective that what should be the strategy.  There are many methods by which you can do rolling computations on original data without splitting it into separate dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

library `slider` is helpful in these cases

```
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

framework %>% group_by(no_passes) %>%
  nest() %>%
  slide(~.x %>% unnest(data), .after = 3, .complete = T) %>%
  subset(map(., length) > 0)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 12 x 8
# Groups:   no_passes [4]
   no_passes game_id home_team team_name player_name                            type_name result_name  subs
       <dbl>   <int> <lgl>     <chr>     <chr>                                  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
 1         1  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Antoine Griezmann                      pass      success         0
 2         1  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Sergio Busquets i Burgos               dribble   success         0
 3         1  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Sergio Busquets i Burgos               dribble   success         0
 4         2  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Sergio Busquets i Burgos               pass      success         0
 5         2  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              dribble   success         0
 6         2  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Héctor Junior Firpo Adames             dribble   success         0
 7         3  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Héctor Junior Firpo Adames             pass      success         0
 8         3  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              dribble   success         0
 9         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              pass      success         0
10         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Jordi Alba Ramos                       dribble   success         0
11         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo dribble   success         0
12         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0

[[2]]
# A tibble: 12 x 8
# Groups:   no_passes [4]
   no_passes game_id home_team team_name player_name                            type_name result_name  subs
       <dbl>   <int> <lgl>     <chr>     <chr>                                  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
 1         2  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Sergio Busquets i Burgos               pass      success         0
 2         2  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              dribble   success         0
 3         2  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Héctor Junior Firpo Adames             dribble   success         0
 4         3  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Héctor Junior Firpo Adames             pass      success         0
 5         3  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              dribble   success         0
 6         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              pass      success         0
 7         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Jordi Alba Ramos                       dribble   success         0
 8         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo dribble   success         0
 9         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0
10         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo pass      success         0
11         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Samuel Yves Umtiti                     dribble   success         0
12         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        dribble   success         0

[[3]]
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   no_passes [4]
   no_passes game_id home_team team_name player_name                            type_name result_name  subs
       <dbl>   <int> <lgl>     <chr>     <chr>                                  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
 1         3  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Héctor Junior Firpo Adames             pass      success         0
 2         3  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              dribble   success         0
 3         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              pass      success         0
 4         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Jordi Alba Ramos                       dribble   success         0
 5         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo dribble   success         0
 6         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0
 7         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo pass      success         0
 8         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Samuel Yves Umtiti                     dribble   success         0
 9         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        dribble   success         0
10         6  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        pass      success         0
11         6  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0

[[4]]
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   no_passes [4]
   no_passes game_id home_team team_name player_name                            type_name result_name  subs
       <dbl>   <int> <lgl>     <chr>     <chr>                                  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
 1         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arturo Erasmo Vidal Pardo              pass      success         0
 2         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Jordi Alba Ramos                       dribble   success         0
 3         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo dribble   success         0
 4         4  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0
 5         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo pass      success         0
 6         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Samuel Yves Umtiti                     dribble   success         0
 7         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        dribble   success         0
 8         6  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        pass      success         0
 9         6  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0
10         7  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  pass      success         0
11         7  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        dribble   success         0

[[5]]
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   no_passes [4]
  no_passes game_id home_team team_name player_name                            type_name result_name  subs
      <dbl>   <int> <lgl>     <chr>     <chr>                                  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
1         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo pass      success         0
2         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Samuel Yves Umtiti                     dribble   success         0
3         5  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        dribble   success         0
4         6  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        pass      success         0
5         6  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  dribble   success         0
6         7  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Gerard Piqué Bernabéu                  pass      success         0
7         7  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        dribble   success         0
8         8  303731 TRUE      Barcelona Clément Lenglet                        pass      success         0
```

If you want to save each item of list as separate output, use `setNames` first then `list2env` to save each item as separate df in `envir = .GlobalEnv`